# Implementation Socket on Service Android

Tags: android, sockets, service

I'm developing a communication with my server by sockets but I've got some issues with android 4.0, 4.1 and 4.2.
But with Android 2.3.3 the same code runs fine.

My code in:
http://paste2.org/98FEtt6f

below my Client Sockets:

```
package com.example.socketservice;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

public class SocketService extends Service implements Runnable {

    Thread connectionWriting;
    Thread connectionListening;

    Socket nsocket; //Network Socket
    BufferedReader nis; //Network Input Stream
    DataOutputStream nos; //Network Output Stream

    String rx;
    String tx = null;

    private static final String SOCKETSERVER = "xxxx";
    private static final int SOCKETPORT = 9999;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i("DEBUG", "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        SocketAddress sockaddr = null;
        try {
            sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(SOCKETSERVER, SOCKETPORT);
            nsocket = new Socket();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", e.getMessage());
        }

        try {
            nsocket.connect(sockaddr, 0);
            if (nsocket.isConnected()) {
             Log.d("DEBUG", "conectado");
             nis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(nsocket.getInputStream()));          
                connectionListening = new Thread(this, "ConnectionListening");
                connectionListening.start();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            nis.close();
            nos.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            nsocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.i("DEBUG", "onDestroy");
    }

    private synchronized void connectionListening() {
        try {
            while ((rx = nis.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.d("DEBUG", "Recebido: " + rx);
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (;;) {
            Log.d("DEBUG", "Lendo");
            connectionListening();
        }
    }
}
```

The errors:

```
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.socketservice.SocketService@4127a928 with Intent { act=SocketService }: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2390)
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:128)
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    at com.example.socketservice.SocketService.onStartCommand(SocketService.java:49)
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2373)
05-29 16:12:28.151: E/AndroidRuntime(19620):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Show us the method containing line 49 of SocketService.java **and indicate which is line 49**

Comment: I edited my ask, Above my code.

Comment: And which is line 49???

Comment: As a guess, your real problem is a NetworkOnMainThread exception (would fit with the working on older versions but now newer), but you failed to post that earlier message because your first catch block is making it too quiet.